# How to ge the maximum frequency of the Integers in Array?

Tags: java

I was asked a program to write in codility test exam to write a function that check the maximum frequency of a integers in array A in return the value :
for example:

```
A[0]: 10
A[1]: 7
A[2]: 10
A[3]: 10
```

Will produce output as 10

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
  int count = 1, tempCount;
  int mostOften = A[0];
  int temp = 0;
  for (int iCounter = 0; iCounter < (A.length - 1); iCounter++)
  {
    temp = A[iCounter];
    tempCount = 0;
    for (int jCounter = 1; jCounter < A.length; jCounter++)
    {
      if (temp == A[jCounter])
        tempCount++;
    }
    if (tempCount > count)
    {
      mostOften = temp;
      count = tempCount;
    }
  }
  return mostOften;
}
}
```

Comment: You should only need a single pass through the array. You have a nested loop, so you need to be rid of that.

Comment: Also, by "use java SE 8" I guess they are telling you to use streams. Use `Arrays.stream()` to create a stream out of an array.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to stream the array and convert it to a frequency map, reverse sort it by the count, and take the first element:

```
public int solution(int[] a) {
    return Arrays.stream(a)
                 .boxed()
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy
                              (Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                 .entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Long> comparingByValue().reversed())
                 .findFirst()
                 .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                 .get();
}
```